# Statistic calculation

Tags: c#, statistics, weighted

this is a question related to statistic calculation. The process that I will be going through is sampling survey.  I will have a fluctuating sample on a daily basis.

I will write a program to process data. After the data is imported into the database. I will have to assign weighting to each group, to make the sample resemble actual ratio in the .

Can anyone tell me if there is any useful tools/ library that I can make use of for this function? i.e interpolation, extrapolation or weighted sample?

Although i will be writing this program in C#, solution in others language or software is welcomed too, e.g. R etc.

Answer (score 0):

For statistical calculations in C# I recommend ILNumerics library.

[ILNumerics home page](http://ilnumerics.net/)